# I get implicit declaration of function strncmp

Tags: c

I get "implicit declaration of function 'strncmp' isinvalid in C99" when use strncmp (xcode 4/ gcc version 4.2.1)
How to avoid this ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From the `strncmp(3)` man page:

> ```
> #include <string.h>
> ```

Answer (score 8):

Did you forget to `#include <string.h>`?